# AES encryption in Java, Decryption in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, java, encryption, aes

I am developing an App(Java) where a private key will be encrypted and send to server. The server will send the key to a webpage where it will be decrypted and used(Javascript).

Right now i have the code, but it's not working.
The decryption fails.

The encryption should work like this:

The Javacode(Encrypt):

Key -> Encoded -> Base64Encoded -> AESEncrypted -> Base64Encoded

```
    public static Keys genKeys(String password){
        KeyPair keypair = genKeyPair();
        Keys keys = new Keys(keypair.getPublic(), encryptKey(keypair.getPrivate(), password));
        return keys;
    }

    public static String encryptKey(PrivateKey priv, String password){
        byte[] encodedKey = priv.getEncoded();
        String base64Key = encodeBase64(encodedKey);
        return encryptWithAES(base64Key.getBytes(), password);
    }

    protected static String encryptWithAES(byte[] msg, String password){
        try {
            String salt = new String(Hex.encodeHex(generateRandom(keySize / 8)));
            String iv = new String(Hex.encodeHex(generateRandom(IV_SIZE / 8)));
            SecretKeyFactory factory = SecretKeyFactory.getInstance("PBKDF2WithHmacSHA1");
            KeySpec spec = new PBEKeySpec(password.toCharArray(), Hex.decodeHex(salt.toCharArray()), iterationCount, keySize);
            SecretKey secretKey = new SecretKeySpec(factory.generateSecret(spec).getEncoded(), "AES");
            Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES/CBC/PKCS5Padding");
            cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, secretKey, new IvParameterSpec(Hex.decodeHex(iv.toCharArray())));
            byte[] encrypted = cipher.doFinal(msg);
            String encryptedBase64 = encodeBase64(encrypted);
            return salt + iv + encryptedBase64;
        } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException | InvalidKeySpecException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (NoSuchPaddingException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (InvalidKeyException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IllegalBlockSizeException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (BadPaddingException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (InvalidAlgorithmParameterException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (DecoderException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return null;
    }


    public static String encodeBase64(byte[] encoded){
        return Base64.encodeToString(encoded, Base64.NO_PADDING);
    }
```

The Javascriptcode(Decrypt):

Base64Encoded -> EncryptedKey -> DecryptedKey

```
                var key = decryptAES(password, keyBase64)
                var decrypt = new JSEncrypt();
                decrypt.setPrivateKey(key);

                var lon = decrypt.decrypt(json.lon);
                var lat = decrypt.decrypt(json.lat);
                var lonLat = new OpenLayers.LonLat(lon, lat)

}

function decryptAES(password, cipherText) {
    keySize = 256;
    ivSize = 128;
    iterationCount = 1867;

    let ivLength = ivSize / 4;
    let saltLength = keySize / 4;
    let salt = cipherText.substr(0, saltLength);
    let iv = cipherText.substr(saltLength, ivLength);
    let encrypted = cipherText.substring(ivLength + saltLength);
    let key = CryptoJS.PBKDF2(password, CryptoJS.enc.Hex.parse(salt), {
        keySize: keySize / 32,
        iterations: iterationCount
    });
    let cipherParams = CryptoJS.lib.CipherParams.create({
        ciphertext: CryptoJS.enc.Base64.parse(encrypted)
    });
    let decrypted = CryptoJS.AES.decrypt(cipherParams, key, {iv: CryptoJS.enc.Hex.parse(iv)});
    return decrypted.toString(CryptoJS.enc.Utf8);
}
```

Does somebody know what I did wrong?

Comment: Did you debug the salt & iv on Javascript side? Did you debug which key was generated on Java- and on Javascript side?  I don't see the keySize, ivSize and number of iterations on Java-side. Why don't you run a minimal example that only does the encryption with sample data and try to decrypt the ciphertext on Javascript side without "privateKey part". Last: you are decrypting the data to a string but the RSA private key is an (encoded) byte array that will have a lot of bytes that are not printable so you should leave it in a byte array for your next steps.

Comment: the keysize, etc. are the on the java side
```
    private static final int IV_SIZE = 128;
    private static final int IV_LENGTH = IV_SIZE / 4;
    private static int keySize = 256;
    private static int iterationCount = 1867;
    private static int saltLength = keySize /4;
```

I already debuged it and salt & iv where fine. The privatekey is encoded as a base64 string before encrypted, so that shouldn't be either the problem.

I created a smaller unit and don't find my mistake why the encryption doesn't work. I've just got an empty string after decrypting in javascript.

Comment: I've found the error. It was caused cause of the base64. I am still not sure what the problem was, i changed from Base64.encodeToString to DatatypeConverter.printBase64Binary and it worked. One difference i see in the output is that it includes padding, but don't know if this was necessary. Nevertheless it works! :)

Comment: I'm glad to read the good news :-)